# Jenkins - maven does not compile build: could not find artifact

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, dependencies, pom.xml

So I setup my maven build on jenkins but it does not compile, it does not find the plugins
(if I remove this plugin it gives the same error for the next one)

Locally I can build/compile and run.

> [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1 or
> one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.8.1 in xxx-Repo
> (http://nlxdsmcv166.srvfarm4-eur.xxx-group.com:8081/artifactory/repo)
> -> [Help 1]

here is my pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>testing</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>

        <cucumber.version>7.2.3</cucumber.version>
        <selenium.version>4.1.2</selenium.version>
        <awaitility.version>4.2.0</awaitility.version>
        <assertj.version>3.22.0</assertj.version>
        <commonsmodel.version>5.3.3</commonsmodel.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
        <commons-lang3.version>3.12.0</commons-lang3.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
            <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
            <version>${awaitility.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>${assertj.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>TestExecutor</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                            <includes>
                                <includes>**/TestExecutor.java</includes>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                    <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <includes>
                        <includes>**/TestExecutor.java</includes>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Your repository does not contain those plugins or is not allowed to download them from central repository or is wrong configured...

Comment: @khmarbaise The error says indeed it does not find these plugins. As you can see in the pom the dependencies/plugins are set so these are to be downloaded from the maven repository. I don't know what you mean with "wrong configured".

the only thing I can use from your answer is "not allowed to download them from central repository" but why wouldn't I be allowed to do this. For every other Jenkins build (different server) I don't have this issue. Thanks for your answer though